# Ubuntu/Nautilus - connect to server: is it possible to disable moving folders?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, file-management, ubuntu-12.04

Sometimes I use Nautilus on Ubuntu to connect to a remote SSH server. I can browse folders easier and open and edit files remotely in my local editor. One thing I'm concerned about is accidentally moving folders. I've seen this happen with several people, not in this situation, always on a Windows machine, always someone who isn't that experienced with the mouse.

It hasn't happened to me, but still I don't like the idea that it could happen. So I'm wondering if this could be prevented somehow, only remotely. Another file manager would also be acceptable, because I still want to be able to move folders locally in Nautilus.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Moving folders from where to where?

Comment: So, basically you want to have nautilus open ssh connections with read only access?

Comment: It looks like the OP wants something more specific: disabling drag&drop in nautilus or a file browser without d&d.

Comment: You're right @user863458. I would want to disable d&d in Nautilus or another filemanager. Cut and paste are enough. When opening a file in an editor, with the filebrowser of the editor itself, it works like I want it to. (In Windows you can move and delete files and folders like this, but I think that is bad practise.) This avoids the risk of moving folders and files. However, if a filemanager could do this, that would be easier in many situations where you want to keep the filemanager open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem. I installed jEdit and use that as editor. I used Sublime, which I really like, but it has one flaw when editing files on a remote server. I can open them from Nautilus of course, but that has the risk of moving folders. I can open the filebrowser in Sublime, which opens at the root of the remote server. It doesn't remember the location of the current opened file.

jEdit has its own browser, but it had another problem, because it resetted ownership and permissions for files, which resulted in files that were not readable by Apache. This issue was solved with jEdit 5.